# Calculate time difference between two timestamp with additional conditions in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I would like to get the total number of hours,minute, and seconds difference between two timestamp fields based on starting and ending time in postgres

Table `supermarket` has fields `opening_time` and `closing_time`

Table `orders` have the fields `order_id`, `arrived_date`, and `picked_date`

I want to calculate the total time spend to pick an order. (The orders can be picked only the supermarket is open but the orders will get placed and queued anytime in the day)

**Condition**: The total picking time should be calculated considering the opening and closing time of the store.

Example

Consider `opening_time` is `09:00:00` and `closing_time` is `22:00:00`

Case 1: if an order arrives on `2020-09-08 10:00:00` and is picked at `2020-09-08 12:00:00`, then the total picking time should be `02 hours`

Case 2: if an order arrives on `2020-09-08 06:00:00` and is picked at `2020-09-08 12:00:00`, then the total picking time should be `03 hours`, not `06 hours` considering the opening time

Case 3: if an order arrives on `2020-09-08 23:00:00` and is picked next day at `2020-09-09 10:00:00`, then the total picking time should be `01 hour` considering closing and opening time

Comment: What is the datatype for `supermarket.opening_time` and `supermarket.closing_time`?

Comment: @Mike Organek, its Time with timezone

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit more complicated that it would seem to, especially if the ranges may expand over more than 24 hours. The safest solution approach might be a brute-force approach that generates all hours in the range, then filtering and aggregation:

```
select s.*, x.*
from supermarket s
cross join lateral (
    select count(*) no_hours
    from generate_series(s.opening_time, s.closing_time, '1 hour') x(x_time)
    where x_time::time >= '09:00:00'::time and x_time::time < '22:00:00'::time
) x
```

This assumes that the opening and closing dates are truncated to the hour, as shown in your examples. If you want to handle minutes, then:

```
select s.*, x.*
from supermarket s
cross join lateral (
    select count(*) no_minutes
    from generate_series(s.opening_time, s.closing_time, '1 minute') x(x_time)
    where x_time::time >= '09:00:00'::time and x_time::time < '22:00:00'::time
) x
```

Comment: sorry I didn't completely get your approach. Could you please tell me what is x_time the query

Comment: @user3614760: it holds a series of dates between the opening and closing time.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps can simply be subtracted resulting in an interval.

```
test=# select '2020-09-08 12:00:00'::timestamp - '2020-09-08 10:00:00'::timestamp;
 ?column? 
----------
 02:00:00
(1 row)
```

That interval can then be formatted with [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

```
test=# select to_char('2020-09-08 12:00:00'::timestamp - '2020-09-08 10:00:00'::timestamp, 'HH24 hours MI "minutes"');
       to_char       
---------------------
 02 hours 00 minutes
(1 row)
```

---

To get the correct interval considering opening and closing time, you need a little bit of logic to figure out the actual picking start time.

```
select
case
when arrived_date::time < opening_time
  -- It arrived before you're open. Start when you open that day.
  arrived_date::date + opening_time
when arrived_date::time > closing_time
  -- It arrived after you closed. Start when you open tomorrow.
  arrived_date::date + '1 day'::interval + opening_time
else
  -- It arrived while you're open. Start when it arrives.
  arrived_date
end as picking_start
```

The trick is to cast `arrived_date` to `time`, truncating the date part, to compare with the opening and closing times. Similarly, we can cast `arrived_date` to `date` and use just the date part, then add the opening time. This assumes that `arrived_date` is a `timestamp` and that `opening_time` and `closing_time` are `time` columns.

This could be [condensed into a function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-create-function/) for easy use.

Comment: Thanks, @Schwern. It will work when I don't have the additional conditions. for case 2 and case 3, it will not give the expected result

Comment: thanks. it is working fine when we don't have a day gap for more than 1 day. How do I manage if the order is picked after 5 days as the second when will manage the only 1-day condition

Comment: @user3614760 Good question. I can't think of an elegant way off the top of my head. I'd suggest asking that as its own question.